# How to match specific ID to list of ID's

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure my title is definitive enough, but here's my dilemma.
Firstly, I have two database tables.

The first one lists all specialitities like this:
ID, Description

The second table stores a practitioner ID with a Specialititiy ID from the above table.

So I have say table 1 with 100 specialitities listed in it.

And in table 2 I have say Practitioner ID 1 with say 5 of those specialitities.
Example:

```
Practitoner ID, Specialitiy ID
123,31
123,45
123,67
123,68
123,81
```

Now, I want to edit those through a form.

I can list all the specialities through a loop through an array of all the specialitities, including a checkbox adjacent to each speciality.
But how do I check the box matching those specialitities listed for the practitioner?

I have a PHP function that gets all the specialitities from the specialitities table and I then loop through that array to list them all, with a checkbox for all of them.

I also have a PHP function that gets all the specialitity ID's for a specific practitioner.

Is there a method of matching the ID of the speciality from the practitioners table with the speciality listed on the form, and checking the box?

I'm not sure I've made myself as clear as I should here, but it might make sense!

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" ... />`?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you will need to work with Javascript. That's because the interaction you are looking for is on the client side and PHP has nothing to do.

Comment: Can you show your current HTML source that is output for the input form?

Comment: @Mark B - yes, that's what I want displayed if there is a match.

Comment: @Babblo - I don't think I need JS to do this.

Comment: Here's some of my markup...
`<?php
$spec = getAllSpec();
foreach ($spec as $S) {
    echo '<div style="float:left; padding:5px; border:1px solid #aaaaaa; margin:2px; width:190px;">';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="spec[]" />';
    echo $S->speciality;
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
`

Comment: Pretty difficult to answer because we would need to see more of your code. I would guess that you need to load the practitioners specialities into an array and then when you loop through the $spec array, check if the ID for that speciality is in the array for that practitioners specialities using in_array - http://us3.php.net/in_array. If it is in the array then add the `checked="checked"` part to the markup for the input.